# How can you tell new Blink based Edge apart from old EdgeHTML via its userAgent?

Tags: microsoft-edge, user-agent, blink

With the [2018 Microsoft Edge team announcement](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdge/blob/7d69268e85e198cee1c2b452d888ac5b9e5995ca/README.md) that Edge is changing browser engines to Blink, it is not obvious how to compensate for EdgeHTML specific bugs and weirdnesses by looking at User-Agent strings (for oddities you can't feature detect any better way). When this need arises, what reliably tells the two browser engines apart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your site is being targeted for [UA string overrides](https://winaero.com/blog/microsoft-edge-chromium-dynamically-changes-its-user-agent/), you can't: depending on what those overrides say, the user-agent will supposedly either pretend to be the old Edge, or a corresponding Chrome browser.

Otherwise, the trick is to scan `navigator.userAgent` for the substring `Edg/` (no trailing `e` before the slash), which is its default setting. The old Edge would have `Edge/` there, instead. Example agent strings:

- **new Edge** (default): `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3763.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/75.0.131.0`
- **old Edge** (white lie): `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763`
- **Chrome** (white lie): `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3763.0 Safari/537.36`